Размер динамического массива и ошибка выделения памяти
В рамках решения вопроса Как загрузить очень большой текстовый файл в TStringList? обнаружил следующую интересную вещь:
На компьютере 192 Гб оперативной памяти, системой и виртуальным диском заняты 42 Гб, то есть свободной - условно 150 Гб. Работаю с данными секвенирования генома, фактически - текстовыми файлами. Поскольку данные используются в программе неоднократно (кратность использования от 200 раз и выше), гружу их в память (ANSI, 1 символ = 1 байт) в виде динамического массива строк ANSIString. Столкнулся с тем, что не могу создать массив размером более 95 с копейками гигабайтов. Вылетает с ошибкой: Fatal: Out of memory, причём не важно, расширяю ли я массив в процессе чтения файла или сразу пытаюсь создать его таким большим. Причем я могу создать массив 94 Гб и тут же еще один массив в 32Гб.
Как вы считаете, это особенность материнской платы в реализации доступа к памяти? (На работе рабочая станция на ThreadRipper'е с 256Гб не имеет такой проблемы.)
Есть ли идеи, как это обойти? MemoryMapped файлы использовать как-то не хочется: ставил 192Гб именно потому, что стандартный размер данных в наших исследованиях 102Гб. Когда-то вроде для ещё TurboPascal существовал модуль, поддерживающий "разряженные массивы", есть ли что-то подобное для Delphi? Сейчас обхожусь полубайтовым кодированием, но это во многом - полумера.
P.S. Проверил на DevStudio, та же самая проблема и у детища Microsoft, то есть дело не в менеджере памяти языка.
P.P.S. Да, на ThreadRipper'е не получилось создать массив более 126.89 Гб под Windows 10. Завтра поставлю на эту машину MS Server, посмотрим. Но все равно - более 100 Гб получилось.

Может есть смысл установить серверную версию ОС?

Для win10 ограничение кажется на 128ГБ виртуального куска. Но, я подозреваю, 128ГБ это с учетом служебных данных самого менеджера памяти. При таком большом объёме наверное львиная доля памяти уходит на информацию о страницах. Но это только догадка. Нету 128ГБ оперативки чтобы проверять/тестить )))

@sibedir Да, вот как-то на домашнем компьютере серверная операционка особо не нужна :) Опять-таки, не факт, что это поможет.

Ну на серверной ос там кусок может терабайтами измеряться. 16 вроде бы

@sibedir На threadripper'е тоже windows 10, такой проблемы нет. Именно это меня и смущает. Завтра попробую там создать массив 128+ Гб.

Ryzen Threadripper, 192ГБ ОЗУ живут же люди ))) <3

У вас строки с заданной длиной или обычные динамические? Просто во втором случае непонятно - массив строк  - это массив указателей, он непосредственно займёт всего несколько гигабайт, а память под тела строк же будет отдельно в куче выделяться.

@MBo до 250, поэтому я по-старинке пользуюсь shortstring с заданной длиной

А какое распределение длин строк? Не выгоднее использовать динамические строки? И в массиве shortstrings  они лежат единым куском, что в данном случае создаёт для вас проблему (воспроизвести которую мало кто может просто физически)

@MBo Ну, разумеется, зависит от запуска. Но, 150 - 250, причем длина определена заранее. И если сказано - 200, значит, 200. Поэтому динамические строки, на мой вкус, использовать смысла не было (учитывая, что с shortsring Delphi работает чуть быстрее). Впрочем, могу попробовать, но, подозреваю, толку не будет :)

Если проблема в том, что 96 гигабайт одним куском не выделяется, то ansistring будут распределены иначе. Альтернатива -  ваши же shortstring в динамическом массиве из двух статических по 64G

@ViktorTomilov Динамические строки ещё и память едят по (16 + x*) байт на строку - это тоже надо иметь в виду. *x - это сколько менеджер памяти выделяет на каждый выделенный блок под заголовки. Возможно, оптимальнее будет действительно один массив ShortString разбить на несколько?.. Типа сделать array of array [0..chunk - 1] of shotrstring и индексировать его arr[index div chunk, index mod chunk] := ....

@Mbo Да вот уже нашел модуль для Delphi, реализующий разряженные массивы. Буду пробовать.

Разреженные массивы -  в которых много пустых элементов. Вам такое зачем?

@Mbo Ну, вот тоже сейчас сижу, читаю справку и не могу понять... Считал, что этот модуль позволяет в куче выделять максимальные фрагменты и создавать там массивы, предлагая единый интерфейс, ан нет :(

Мне кажется, под массив массивов не так трудно переделать код. Если обращений в коде много, можно сделать класс с индексированным свойством, тогда основной код не изменится вообще (ну будет дополнительный уровень косвенности при обращении, по сравнению с обработкой строки это кот наплакал)

@Alekcvp Да, это был второй вариант, как действовать. Но, поскольку в свое время для слабых машин мною был создан полубайтовый подход к ДНК-последовательностям (AGTCU + вырожденности, - весь алфавит), причём куча функций написана на ассемблере, т.е. весьма быстра, обхожусь старыми наработками. Но проблема не исчезнет, с ней надо что-то делать, так как массивы данных только растут

@MBo Собственно, в предыдущем комментарии ответил, как сейчас справляюсь. Мне интересно иное - это стандартный подход производителей мат. плат не для серверов или как?

Тут я не знаю. И ограничение какое-то ни туда, ни сюда - и не 64, и не 128 гиг. Как настройка 32-битной винды была, которая включала 3 гига адресного пространства, а здесь 3x32

@MBo   Похоже, это все-таки адресация памяти мат. платы: сейчас попробовал убрать виртуальный диск, массив получилось создать 112Гб. Включил виртуальный диск и увеличил емкость - упал размер создаваемого массива. Судя по всему, мат. плата дает доступ к памяти двумя кусками: 128 и 64, причем Windows грузит все свое в кусок 64Гб. Других объяснений у меня нет

Из другого вопроса: У вашего железа (процессора/контроллера памяти) разведено 36 адресных линий, больше оно адресовать физической памяти не способно. В общем, нужны спецы по железу

@ViktorTomilov , а какого размера массива в итоге удалось добиться на Threadripper под win10? Или не получилось попробовать?

@sibedir 126.89 Гб

Ого, т.е. работа механизма виртуальной памяти ос может так сильно варьироваться в зависимости от процессора? 126.89 - это же практически теоретический максимум. Интересно. Спасибо.

@sibedir Более того, студенты, которым я дал задание проверить выделение памяти на Threadripper'e под серверной операционкой, утверждают, что 202 Гб спокойно удалось выделить.

@ViktorTomilov, под серверной это да. Там, я так понял, вообще до 16ТБ доходить может. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases

@MBo Не бьется: 36 адресных дают только 64Гб (а получается - больше), к сожалению, не вижу в доках на свою мат. плату таких параметров.
